# looking for a usb to mini pcie adapter

Tags: linux, pcie, network-adapter, adapter

I have some mini pcie wireless cards I want to use with my laptop. I ordered one such device from amazon, but it was a sham, there was litterly no components on  the PCB, there is no way I could have worked. What USB to mini PCIE device do you recommend? Operational with Linux would be a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to find one.

USB and PCIe are two very different technologies supported by the PCH ([Platform Controller Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub)) in the chipset of your PC/Server.

[image]

The I/O portion of the PCH supplies both PCIe and USB interfaces to the system.  However, PCIe being an expansion bus allows you add additional USB controllers to the system; the USB interface doesn't allow you to add PCIe controllers.

You need to us a USB WiFi Adapter compatible with your flavor of Unix.